# Proper upstart config for meteor?

Tags: upstart, vagrant, meteor

I'm hoping to find out how to tell upstart that meteor will fork more than twice?

I followed their instructions at http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#how-to-establish-fork-count to count the forks and it reports 21 times.

This is kind of a non issue in that `stop myapp` and `start myapp` work as expected (they stop and start and do not hang). If its relevant, I am running this in an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit) VM created w/ Vagrant .

```
#!upstart
# Upstart config for running the node application
description "myapp"
author      "My Company"

start on (filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on shutdown

respawn             # restart when job dies
respawn limit 5 60  # give up restart after 5 respawns in 60 seconds
chdir /vagrant

script
  exec sudo -u vagrant MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/project meteor -p 4000
end script
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `meteor run` to host your application in any environment where you'd be using Upstart to manage the process.

`meteor run` is a development-only server, and is very inefficient.

Take a look at https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer - you can use it to convert your Meteor.js app into a 'vanilla' Node.js app with a `package.json`, which you can then run on your Ubuntu VM and manage with Upstart.

Comment: This was asked long before we basically did as you said. We now convert to a standalone node.js app and use init.d scripts to manage the service.